# Multipanel plot - how to omit a graphy from a specific position in a matrix layout

Tags: r

I cannot get the layout command to work.  I want a multi-panel plot with a gap in a specific position, as given by this matrix:

```
mat <- matrix (c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,12), 4, 3)
mat
```

where value 0 represents where I need empty space.  However I get an error message when I run

```
 layout(mat)
```

Using the following does not work either

```
 mat <- matrix (c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1), 4, 3)
```

because when I run

```
  layout.show(12)
```

it only gives me one panel instead of a 3x4 matrix layout.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a number 12 panel, but no number 11.  Try this instead

```
mat <- matrix (c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,11), 4, 3) 
layout(mat)
layout.show(11)
```

[image]